# What Electronic Component Marking On A Circuit Board Is Designated For BF?

Tags: pcb, components, identification

While looking at ESR values for capacitors on a failed Samsung refrigerator circuit board I was looking over other components for telltale signs of failure and spotted an unusual component that I thought was at first a fried diode, but the marking next to it is BF1 which I've never seen before in any circuit board I've worked on.

I've checked the resistance and I'm getting about .02 ohms no matter what the polarity side is + or - on the leads tested.

What is that component labeled BF1?  Is that a fried diode or something else?  It has a tiny hint of dark ring on the far right.  Where the leads come out of the component there seems to be distinct orange coloring on both ends.

[image: Samsung electronic circuit board containing BF1 component in question.]

Comment: Do you have an image of the side of the component, from looking at one of the pins.

Comment: I apologize, I guess I thought that one single image would be sufficient.  I'll have to crack the panel open and get another image to add to the original question, but it looks like the component has been identified as a Bead Ferrite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image you present doesn't present enough information but I highly believe it is a ferrite bead.

My reasoning:

- The symbol being BF1 seems like short for Bead Ferrite 1
- The texture of the component looks awfully like a Ferrite core, but inverted, thus a ferrite bead.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead

Comment: I agree. Any other component would have color bands or text, even a Pico-fuse.